# Powershell get-process query

Tags: powershell

I want to write a simple If Statement which checks if an Process Exists.
If it Exists, something should start.

Like this, but working.. ;)

```
If ((Get-Process -Name Tvnserver.exe ) -eq $True)
{ 
    Stop-Process tnvserver
    Stop-Service tvnserver
    Uninstall...
    Install another Piece of Software
}
Else
{
    do nothing
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will evaluate to true if the process doesn't exist:

```
(Get-Process -name Tvnserver.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null
```

or if you want to change it you can negate the statement as follows:

```
-not ( $(Get-Process -name Tvnserver.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
```

It's important to have have `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to avoid any errors been thrown if a process doesn't exist.

Comment: For negating the condition simply change `-eq $null` to `-ne $null`.

Answer (score 6):

`Get-Process` doesn't return a boolean value and the process name is listed without extension, that's why your code doesn't work. Drop the extension and either check if the result is `$null` as [Musaab Al-Okaidi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053676/1630171) suggested, or cast the result to a boolean value:

```
if ( [bool](Get-Process Tvnserver -EA SilentlyContinue) ) {
  # do some
} else {
  # do other
}
```

If you don't want the script to do anything in case the process isn't running: just omit the `else` branch.